# Mod Rewrite app.php lighttpd

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony, lighttpd

I want to rewrite my Symfony 2 URL so instead of showing

> www.example.com/app.php/path

it shows

> www.example.com/path

How can I do this using lighttpd?

Comment: Symfony2 Standard Edition comes with a *.htaccess* file that has URL rewriting rules that suit the framework. See how you can use (or convert) it on lighttpd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "(.+)" => "/app.php$1"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fresh article about [how to configure Symfony 2 with Lighttpd](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409212824/http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-lighttpd/):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "myhost\.tld" {
    server.document-root = "/home/user/www/myhost/web"

    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^/$" => "$0",
        "^(?!app_dev\.php/)[^\?]+(\?.*)?" => "app.php/$1$2",
    )
}
```

Comment: Sadly that site is down. Luckily the internet archive still has it available:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160409212824/http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-lighttpd/